# Convert from One Base to Another in Java without ParseInt

Tags: java

I'm working on an assignment where I have to have an option to ask the user if they want to convert from any base to any other base. Here is the main the instructor gave us:

```
import java.util.*;

public class CSCD210Lab21
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {

      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

      int choice;

      do
      {
         choice = Lab21Methods.menu(kb);

         switch(choice)
         {
            case 1:  Lab21Methods.convert(kb, 10, 2, '0', '1');
                     break;

            case 2:  Lab21Methods.convert(kb, 10, 8, '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7');
                     break;

            case 3:  Lab21Methods.convert(kb, 10, 16, '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');
                 break;        

            case 4:  int fromBase = Lab21Methods.readBase(kb, "from");       
                     char [] fromBaseValues = Lab21Methods.readBaseValues(kb, fromBase);
                     int toBase = Lab21Methods.readBase(kb, "to");
                     char [] toBaseValues = Lab21Methods.readBaseValues(kb, toBase); 
                     Lab21Methods.convert(kb, fromBase, fromBaseValues, toBase, toBaseValues);
                     break;

            default:  System.out.println("Thanks for using my silly base converter");      
         }// end switch

      }while(choice != 5);

   }// end main

}// end class
```

The main part I'm concerned about is in case 4 in the switch statement. Here is what I have so far:

```
  public static char [] readBaseValues(Scanner kb, int baseVal)
  {
      kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter Base: ");
      baseVal = kb.nextInt();
      kb.nextLine();
      char valArray[] = new char[baseVal];

      for(int i=0; i < valArray.length; i++)
      {   
         System.out.print("Enter Base Value: ");
         valArray[i] = kb.nextLine().charAt(0);
      }      
      System.out.print(valArray);
      return valArray;
   }
   public static int readBase(Scanner kb, String type)
   {
      System.out.println();
      System.out.print("Enter Base To Convert "+type+" : ");
      int num = kb.nextInt();
      return num;
   }
```

I've got no idea how to proceed to convert say a base 10 to a base 2 without using ParseInt. He says if we use ParseInt, we get 0 points. How else do I proceed?

Comment: what about BigInteger? Did he mention something about it?

Comment: From the write-up:
You may not use any Java methods/classes for the base conversion. You must write your own code.

Comment: sorry, I missed that part.

Comment: Why in `readBaseValues()` do you prompt for and read the base?  It was already received in `readBase()` and passed to `readBaseValues()` as an argument.

Comment: How would you fix it so that it functions the same?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to do is to use casting of low level chars.

What you do is convert the char value, which is low level also a number. So:

```
(int) '0'==48 //true
```

What you can do is say

```
String in = "1234";
int sum = 0;
for(char c: in.toCharArray())
   sum += ((int) c)-48;
```

For conversion of base, you use the modulo operation. In Java you use the '%' operation for that: 9%5=4.

For instance to convert 9 to base 5, we do:

1. 9/5=1, 9%5=4
2. 1/5=0, 9%5=1

Each time you propagate the remainder of the previous devision. The total number base-5 is now '14', you just write the modulo operations after each other.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `convert()` as your own version of `parseInt()` and `String.valueOf()`.  The method arguments give the bases of the input and output, the symbols in which those numbers are expressed, *and place value of the symbols* in the form of their indices in the digit array.

You need to process the input character by character, finding the place value for each character, and building up the numeric value using the base and the digits' place values.  Then you need to do the reverse to convert the resulting number to a digit string expressed in the output base and symbols.

Since the digit symbols are given as input, you should not assume any specific relationship between their `char` values and the corresponding place values (e.g. the program does not appear to be constrained to make '0' be the digit having place value 0).